# Compress references (elsarticle/natbib)

Tags: natbib, elsarticle

I am writing a journal article for Elsevier. I am finishing it, but I have noted that the references appear not compressed.

For example, in my article the references appear as the following

...[1], [2], [3]

Instead of

...[1–3]

Could anyone help me to fix it?

I am working with the following preamble

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-weight, detect-display-math}
\sisetup{detect-inline-weight=math}
\sisetup{mode=text,per-mode=symbol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\newlength\fwidth
\setlength{\fwidth}{0.8\textwidth}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\usepackage{overpic}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{bicaption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\def\UrlFont{\normalfont}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\journal{Fuel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}


\end{frontmatter}


\cite{jiang2007new,jiang2007progress,hotta2005experience}    

\section*{References}

\bibliography{bilbiography}

\end{document}

\endinput
```

Please use the following citations as `bibliography.bib`:

```
@article{hotta2005experience,
    title={EXPERIENCE OF ESTONIAN OIL SHALE COMBUSTION BASED ON CFB TECHNOLOGY AT NARVA POWER PLANTS.},
    author={Hotta, A and Parkkonen, R and Hiltunen, M and Arro, H and Loosaar, J and Parve, T and Pihu, T and Prikk, A and Tiikma, T},
    journal={Oil shale},
    volume={22},
    number={4},
    year={2005}
}

@article{uibu2009co2,
    title={CO2 mineral sequestration in oil-shale wastes from Estonian power production},
    author={Uibu, Mai and Uus, Mati and Kuusik, Rein},
    journal={Journal of environmental management},
    volume={90},
    number={2},
    pages={1253--1260},
    year={2009},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{jiang2007new,
    title={New technology for the comprehensive utilization of Chinese oil shale resources},
    author={Jiang, XM and Han, XX and Cui, ZG},
    journal={Energy},
    volume={32},
    number={5},
    pages={772--777},
    year={2007},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{jiang2007progress,
    title={Progress and recent utilization trends in combustion of Chinese oil shale},
    author={Jiang, XM and Han, XX and Cui, ZG},
    journal={Progress in Energy and Combustion Science},
    volume={33},
    number={6},
    pages={552--579},
    year={2007},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that you are already using `\cite{a,b,c}`, you can accomplish this by adding the following to your preamble:

```
\biboptions{sort&compress}
```

You can see this in an example I have created on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/zqrcvntkpnyh).

Answer (score 4):

To quote from the [`elsarticle` manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle):

> If you want to add extra options of `natbib.sty`, you may use the options as comma delimited strings as arguments to `\biboptions`command.
>
> [...]
>
> `sort&compress`  sorts and compresses the numbered citations. For
>   example, citation [1,2,3] will become [1–3]

You might therefor achieve the desied result, by including the following line in your preamble:

`\biboptions{sort&compress}`