# Compressing in-line references with natbib and bookdown

Tags: natbib, bookdown

I am using `bookdown` to generate a pdf book with `natbib`, and as of now the in-line references look like this:

`[118,119,120,121,142]`

However, I would like them to compress to:

`[118 - 121,142]`

I use the following in my `preamble`:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{square,comma,numbers}
```

I have tried the following:

- `\biboptions{sort&compress}` in `preamble`, as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434338/compress-references-elsarticle-natbib), this throws the error `undefined control sequence`
- `\setcitestyle{square,comma,numbers,sort&compress}` in `preamble`, as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367391/option-clash-for-package-squarenatbib), this does not change the in-line citations at all, same with `\PassOptionsToPackage{square,comma,numbers,sort&compress}{natbib}` as described in the same post
- `\setcitestyle{numbers,sort&compress}` alone, to see if something was messing it up

I use a slightly modified version of `plainnat.bst`, where I have only changed the `article` and `misc` function to exclude URLs etc. Otherwise it is completely similar to `plainnat.bst`.

In my YAML in the `index.Rmd` file i have specified the following:

```
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
geometry: "left=4cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm"
subparagraph: true
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    fig_caption: yes
    toc: false
    citation_package: natbib
    includes:
      before_body: frontpage.tex
      after_body: after_body.tex
      in_header: preamble.tex
fontsize: 11pt
linestretch: 1.2
documentclass: book
bibliography: [packages.bib, library.bib]
biblio-style: [plainnatnew.bst]
link-citations: yes
```

Any ideas on how to get the compressed numbers?

Working example:

`.bib` file

```
@article{OBrien2011,
  title = {Effect of Diet and Gut Dynamics on the Establishment and Persistence of {{Escherichia}} Coli},
  volume = {157},
  issn = {1350-0872},
  number = {5},
  journal = {Microbiology},
  doi = {10.1099/mic.0.047092-0},
  url = {http://mic.microbiologyresearch.org/content/journal/micro/10.1099/mic.0.047092-0},
  author = {O'Brien, Claire L. and Gordon, David M.},
  month = may,
  year = {2011},
  pages = {1375--1384}
}

@article{Fabrega2009,
  title = {Mechanism of Action of and Resistance to Quinolones},
  volume = {2},
  issn = {17517907},
  number = {1},
  journal = {Microbial Biotechnology},
  doi = {10.1111/j.1751-7915.2008.00063.x},
  url = {http://doi.wiley.com/10.1111/j.1751-7915.2008.00063.x},
  author = {F{\`a}brega, Anna and Madurga, Sergi and Giralt, Ernest and Vila, Jordi},
  month = jan,
  year = {2009},
  pages = {40--61}
}

@article{Chung2002,
  title = {Overexpression of the {{Escherichia}} Coli {{sugE}} Gene Confers Resistance to a Narrow Range of Quaternary Ammonium Compounds},
  volume = {184},
  number = {9},
  journal = {Journal of Bacteriology},
  url = {http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11948170},
  author = {Chung, Y J and Saier Jr., M H},
  year = {2002},
  pages = {2543--2545},
  pmid = {11948170}
}

@article{Dierikx2013a,
  title = {Presence of {{ESBL}}/{{AmpC}} -{{Producing Escherichia}} Coli in the {{Broiler Production Pyramid}}: {{A Descriptive Study}}},
  volume = {8},
  language = {English},
  number = {11},
  journal = {PloS One},
  doi = {ARTN e79005 DOI 10.1371/journal.pone.0079005},
  author = {Dierikx, C M and {van der Goot}, J A and Smith, H E and Kant, A and Mevius, D J},
  year = {2013},
  keywords = {antimicrobial agents,chickens,enterobacteriaceae,epidemiology,humans,impact,poultry,resistance,spectrum-beta-lactamase,transmission},
  pages = {e79005}
}

@article{Blaak2015,
  title = {Distribution, {{Numbers}}, and {{Diversity}} of {{ESBL}}-{{Producing E}}. Coli in the {{Poultry Farm Environment}}},
  volume = {10},,
  number = {8},
  journal = {PloS One},
  doi = {10.1371/journal.pone.0135402},
  url = {http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26270644},
  author = {Blaak, H and {van Hoek}, A H and Hamidjaja, R A and {van der Plaats}, R Q and {Kerkhof-de Heer}, L and {de Roda Husman}, A M and Schets, F M},
  year = {2015},
  pages = {e0135402},
  pmid = {26270644}
}

@article{Kingsford2010,
  title = {Assembly Complexity of Prokaryotic Genomes Using Short Reads},
  volume = {11},
  issn = {1471-2105},
  number = {1},
  journal = {BMC Bioinformatics},
  doi = {10.1186/1471-2105-11-21},
  url = {https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-11-21},
  author = {Kingsford, Carl and Schatz, Michael C. and Pop, Mihai},
  month = dec,
  year = {2010},
  pages = {21}
}
```

`Lorem ipsum [@OBrien2011;Fabrega2009;Chung2002;Dierikx2013a;Kingsford2010]`

Comment: Adding a `MWEB` would help.

Comment: @Denis added an example now

Comment: Please see my answer below to make an appropriate `MWEB`. The whole isea is to be able to cut and paste and compile without bothering.

Comment: Can you confirm the same behaviour with `plainnat`? Can you share the `.tex` document your minimal example generates? `\PassOptionsToPackage` has to precede `\usepackage{natbib}` to be effective.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{OBrien2011,
  title = {Effect of Diet and Gut Dynamics on the Establishment and Persistence of {{Escherichia}} Coli},
  volume = {157},
  issn = {1350-0872},
  number = {5},
  journal = {Microbiology},
  doi = {10.1099/mic.0.047092-0},
  url = {http://mic.microbiologyresearch.org/content/journal/micro/10.1099/mic.0.047092-0},
  author = {O'Brien, Claire L. and Gordon, David M.},
  month = may,
  year = {2011},
  pages = {1375--1384}
}

@article{Fabrega2009,
  title = {Mechanism of Action of and Resistance to Quinolones},
  volume = {2},
  issn = {17517907},
  number = {1},
  journal = {Microbial Biotechnology},
  doi = {10.1111/j.1751-7915.2008.00063.x},
  url = {http://doi.wiley.com/10.1111/j.1751-7915.2008.00063.x},
  author = {F{\`a}brega, Anna and Madurga, Sergi and Giralt, Ernest and Vila, Jordi},
  month = jan,
  year = {2009},
  pages = {40--61}
}

@article{Chung2002,
  title = {Overexpression of the {{Escherichia}} Coli {{sugE}} Gene Confers Resistance to a Narrow Range of Quaternary Ammonium Compounds},
  volume = {184},
  number = {9},
  journal = {Journal of Bacteriology},
  url = {http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11948170},
  author = {Chung, Y J and Saier Jr., M H},
  year = {2002},
  pages = {2543--2545},
  pmid = {11948170}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\citep{Chung2002,Fabrega2009,OBrien2011}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

You will obtain

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, using `\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}` throws this error: `Latex Error: Option clash for package natbib`, as mentioned in one of the pages i linked to, which is why I tried the `\biboptions{sort&compress}` instead, which also gave me an error message. Note that I am using bookdown with RStudio, and not just plain latex